# Sharepoint 2013 search service imsqueryinternal endpoint not found

Tags: search, sharepoint

Search in Sharepoint 2013 gives

Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.

The Search Operational Log shows

w3wp.exe: Query processing component 'net.tcp://server/06CE4A/QueryProcessingComponent1/ImsQueryInternal' changes its status to 'Failed'.

Same errors are shown in the ULS logs.

What has been tried (several times)

1. Resetting the index
2. Recreating QPC
3. Recreating complete search service
4. Clearing cache
5. Restarting search service and host controller
6. Restarting IIS
7. Restarting Server
8. Running PSConfig
9. Running Configuration Wizard.
10. Banging head on the wall as well as hitting the server ;)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Imran

Comment: btw, all the services are running and services and search topology component are showing green ticks. Search crawl has 20000 items, 0 query in search queries. Seems like search never reaches the QPC

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue that we resolved by looking at the firewall of the Search Server.  We turned on dropped packet logging and noticed that every time one of our front end servers performed a search, packets were dropped from port 808.  We enabled incoming TCP on port 808 on the search server and that resolved our issue.